# Responsive text alignment in Twitter's Bootstrap 2.x

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, text-alignment

In bootstrap, I am trying to achieve a design that groups two pieces of text (a label, **A**, and some content, **B**) by having them near each other, like so:

```
A (right-aligned) | B (left-aligned)
```

Using responsive layouts in bootstrap, this looks great until the grid is stacked on narrow windows. Then it becomes:

```
                       |      A (right-aligned)
B (left-aligned)       |
```

... and it looks as though the two are no longer related.

I would prefer that once stacked, the elements would be either both centered or both left-aligned.

I know that I can use the .visible-* and .hidden-* classes to fix this, but that feels like a hack. Is there a simple way to change text alignment in response to bootstrap stacking parts of the grid?

Comment: did you tried `pull-left` and `pull-right`?

Comment: Use a media query with max-width just short of the combined width of the elements and align A to the left

Answer (score 10):

In Bootstrap 3 using LESS, I added the following:

```
/* Defaults */
.text-center-sm,
.text-center-md,
.text-center-lg,
.text-right-sm,
.text-right-md,
.text-right-lg { text-align: inherit; }

/* Define xs styles after defaults so they take precedence */
.text-center-xs { text-align: center; }
.text-right-xs { text-align: right; }

/* Small grid */
@media (min-width: @screen-tablet) {
  .text-center-sm, .text-center-xs { text-align: center; }
  .text-right-sm, .text-right-xs { text-align: right; }
}

/* Medium grid */
@media (min-width: @screen-desktop) {
  .text-center-md, .text-center-sm, .text-center-xs { text-align: center; }
  .text-right-md, .text-right-sm, .text-right-xs { text-align: right; }
}

/* Large grid */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-desktop) {
  .text-center-lg, .text-center-md, .text-center-sm, .text-center-xs {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .text-right-lg, .text-right-md, .text-right-sm, .text-right-xs {
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

If you're not using LESS, change `@screen-tablet` to `768px`, `@screen-desktop` to `992px`, and `@screen-lg-desktop` to `1200px`.

Answer (score 1):

To right align (left align will be default) you can use text-align:right on your span. To make this responsive use media queries to only apply it on big screens:

```
@media (min-width:768px)
{
  .text-right-responsive {text-align:right;}
  .text-left-responsive {text-align:left;}
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="span6 text-right-responsive">A (right-aligned)</div>
<div class="span6 text-left-responsive">B (left-aligned)</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14809431/1596547 since version 2.3 Twitter's Bootstrap also have text-* classes. So you could use: `<div class="span6 text-right">A (right-aligned)</div>`. Also this class is not responsive. text-right only adds text-align:right to your element's style. So you need media queries to reset this too. Reset the text alignment for small screens:

```
 @media (max-width:767px)
 {
    .text-right {text-align:left;}
    .text-left {text-align:left;}
 }
```

The **pull-right / pull-left classes** add a float to the element. So to use them you will need an extra wrapper:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6"><span class="pull-right">A (right-aligned)</span></div>
  <div class="span6"><span class="pull-left">B (left-aligned)</span></div>
</div> 
</div>
```

In this case you can use media queries also. Now you need to reset the float for small screens:

```
@media (max-width:767px)
{
  .pull-right {float:none;}
  .pull-left {float:none;}
}
```

DEMO: http://bootply.com/66024