# Can each bootstrap navbar link be spaced individually

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, grid, alignment

For example I have a navbar with the following links :

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Business Owner's Learn More</a>
  </li>
  <li id="login" class="nav-item ">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

All of these currently align to the left, but I would like to place the `#login` link to the right, is this possible with bootstrap? Should I be using something else such as flex box, grid, etc... ?

Answer (score 0):

As with most things in CSS, there are dozens of way to do this. For starters, you can give `#login` a css property of `float: right;`. More on float [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).

Another newer way would be to use flexbox. In this case, it would look something like adding `display: flex;` on the parent, followed by `justify-content: space-between;`. [Here's](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) a great guide to flexbox.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809313/twitter-bootstrap-float-div-right) a stack overflow question on aligning text the Bootstrap way.

Answer (score 0):

Add `d-flex` class on ul and `align-self-end` on the li that you want to align to the right.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto d-flex">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Business Owner's Learn More</a>
  </li>
  <li id="login" class="nav-item align-self-end">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**OR**
Add `text-right` class to the required li

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Business Owner's Learn More</a>
  </li>
  <li id="login" class="nav-item text-right">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```