# Bootstrap class "text-center" not working

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal

```
<div class="input-group Flugo_group">
     <h4 class="text-center">or</h4>
</div>
```

i am try to show in center but not working.second time using position relative but not working properly in responsive design.
[image: center]

Comment: Perhaps you have styles conflicts with other components. Post a link or put your code in the editor and it will be easier to help you

Comment: Flugo_group class is not any components it's own define class for bootstrap customize. i am using only bootstrap

Comment: Now I am using bootstrap 4. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15140080/5724267. And it's work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Bootstrap 3

[v3 Text Alignment Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment)

```
<p class="text-left">Left aligned text.</p>
<p class="text-center">Center aligned text.</p>
<p class="text-right">Right aligned text.</p>
<p class="text-justify">Justified text.</p>
<p class="text-nowrap">No wrap text.</p>
```

## Bootstrap 4

[v4 Text Alignment Docs](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/typography/#text-alignment)

```
<p class="text-xs-left">Left aligned text on all viewport sizes.</p>
<p class="text-xs-center">Center aligned text on all viewport sizes.</p>
<p class="text-xs-right">Right aligned text on all viewport sizes.</p>

<p class="text-sm-left">Left aligned text on viewports sized SM (small) or wider.</p>
<p class="text-md-left">Left aligned text on viewports sized MD (medium) or wider.</p>
<p class="text-lg-left">Left aligned text on viewports sized LG (large) or wider.</p>
<p class="text-xl-left">Left aligned text on viewports sized XL (extra-large) or wider.</p>
```

Comment: That page indicates the non-viewport-specific class should work as well.

Comment: `display:block` might be needed also.

Comment: With bootstrap 4, `text-center` works the same as `text-xs-center`. In my case I had forgotten to [install bootstrap before react-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56539469/332578)

Answer (score 28):

I was facing the same problem in Bootstrap 4.1.0. Here is what I figured out:

I was doing this (having my paragraph inside div with class "row"):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="background-color: #009688;">
       <p class="text-center" style="color: #fff;"> Meet me at</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Later I removed the class and it worked.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div style="background-color: #009688;">
       <p class="text-center" style="color: #fff;"> Meet me at</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Same thing happened to me in Bootstrap 4.1, had to remove the row class.

Answer (score 7):

In Bootstrap 4, for aligning center position:
Use class= "mx-auto"
example:

```
<p class="mx-auto">Kailash</p>
```

It will align the text horizontally center position.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it this way.

```
<section className="d-flex">
    <span className="mx-auto">Hello World!</span>
</section>
```

Bootstrap v5.

Answer (score 2):

The input group field has `display: flex` which causes elements inside, including your paragraph, to not be at 100% width, but the width of their content only. The text is centred, however, the length of the paragraph is only as long as the characters `or`. To counter this you could use `mx-auto` which would centre the paragraph using margin auto on the X-axis, or `w-100` which will make the paragraph be 100% the length of the parent instead of just something like `width: max-content`. The issue here isn't with the Bootstrap utilities, but rather flexbox.

I would strongly suggest that you use input group as shown in the documentation only. This is intended to create an inline group of buttons and it is not expected to have any other elements. I would altogether suggest removing the input group class.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely that you have your own stylesheet and your `<h4>` tag has `text-align: left;` or something like that. It could be `.input-group` or `.Flugo_group` as well. We'd need to see your code though.

Edit: Or even something as simple as what contains any of your code could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

UzumakiL answer was ok so my answer is based on his example.

I tried to fix it bootstrap way and found you need to add a col to center the header.

Try add col then center the header in there.

Something like that:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row bg-dark">
       <div class="col-12 text-center">
           <p class="text-success"> Text Center</p>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle solution](https://jsfiddle.net/ebshdvo9/)