# Align text right in-line with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm currently using bootstrap 4. I'm trying to align text right on my card header, I tried using `ml-auto` but it didn't work. What could be the solution?

[image: See the red area]

Here's my card header code:

```
<div class="card-header bg-info text-white">
  <a href="#" class="text-white"><i class="fa-th"></i> Media Library</a>
  <a href="#" class="text-white ml-auto">Add Media</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order for the `ml-auto` class to work you just need to add the `d-flex` class (display:flex) to the parent element like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card-header bg-info text-white d-flex">
    <a href="#" class="text-white"><i class="fa-th"></i> Media Library</a>
    <a href="#" class="text-white ml-auto">Add Media</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is only answer that works, thank you!

Comment: done, thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the version of Bootstrap you are using

## Bootstrap 3

use the class `text-right`

## Bootstrap 4

In newest version, you can use the class `text-lg-right` using the viewport size you prefer of course

## Additionals

You check more in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829608/bootstrap-text-align-class-for-inside-table) or check the [official documentation v4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Bootstrap, I use the Materialize but you could add normal styling to it,
on your

```
 <a href="#" class="text-white" style="text-align: right;"><i class="fa-th"></i> Media Library</a>
```

This would align only you anchor tag to the right

Answer (score 0):

Use this cord...

```
<div class="card-header bg-info text-white" style="text-align:right">
       <a href="#" class="text-white"><i class="fa-th"></i> Media Library</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: but this would align all of my text on the right side, I want only a particular text to align right, the title should remain on the left side.

Comment: ah ok... put this cord for your text line it works fine... I use this ... Do not use this for the whole row....

Comment: <div class="card-header bg-info text-white" >
       <a href="#" class="text-white" style="text-align:right"><i class="fa-th"></i> Media Library</a>
 </div>

Answer (score 0):

Use this class **text-right**..

```
<div class="card-header bg-info text-white text-right">
   <a href="#" class="text-white"><i class="fa-th"></i> Media Library</a>
</div>
```