# Bootstrap CSS for two classes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a `div` tag with `.col-xs-12 .col-md-4` and `.left`. I want that when the application is started in a pc, the application use the CSS for `.col-md-4` `.left`, and when is started in a smarthphone, only use `.col-xs-12` CSS.

I already test this:

```css
.col-md-4.left {
  text-align: left;
}

.col-xs-12 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 left">
  My Test
</div>
```

The idea is that when the application is in a pc, the `div` will be a `.col-md-4` with `text-align: left`, and in a smarthphone will be `-col-xs-12` with  `text-align: center`

Comment: did try using media queries?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/text/#text-alignment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap - Text-align class for inside a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829608/bootstrap-text-align-class-for-inside-a-table)

Answer (score 2):

Try using media queries, you can put specific breakpoints.

Reference : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
    .example {
      padding: 20px;
      color: white;
    }
    /* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .example {background: red;}
    }
    
    /* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
      .example {background: green;}
    }
    
    /* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      .example {background: blue;}
    } 
    
    /* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
      .example {background: orange;}
    } 
    
    /* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
      .example {background: pink;}
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h2>Typical Media Query Breakpoints</h2>
    <p class="example">Resize the browser window to see how the background color of this paragraph changes on different screen sizes.</p>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use both col-xs-12 and col-md-4, bootstrap works on both classes.
Here is my bootstrap4 website, I am also a beginner of bootstrap-css developer, so I make this [bootstrap-css website.](https://www.ilove-map.com/poetry/page1)

Hope you will be another good bootstraper!

Answer (score 0):

Use this class `text-center text-md-left`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 text-center text-md-left">
  My Test
</div>
```

[more info](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/text/#text-alignment)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 text-md-left text-center">
  My Test
</div>
```

You can remove those css and add these two class text-md-left text-center. Note this only works in bootstrap4.